# apache not running on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache2, xampp, wampserver

I have an issue on my windows 7, I want to work on php so i tried everything but can not get it done.  It always gives 
**Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at nazar-studio:8080.**

These are the things i had tried:

- Installed WAMP
- Installed XAMPP
- Installed Apache
- Installed IIS
- stoped the http service
- blocked anti-virus
- un-installed anti-virus
- stoped skype
- Also tried this [link](http://www.cameroncooke.com/2009/01/25/windows-7-uses-port-80-and-makes-it-impossible-to-install-apache-solution/)

and there are many other things i had done, but invain.

When i check the port using **netstat -an** it shows the ports listening, i tried many different ports, but nothing works.

Can any one help me, I am really struck and frustrated due to it.

Comment: what ip does `nazar-studio` map to? Apache would have to be specfically listening to *:8080 or nazar-studio:8080 for a connection to get established. How does port 8080 show up in your netstat output?

Comment: i tried every thing, nazar-studio is my pc name, also tried 127.0.0.1, localhost, also tried many different ports, but nothing works.

Comment: What exactly shows up in the netstat output for port 8080?

Comment: TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: try telnetting to nazar-studio:8080 from the machine itself, and from another machine, see if you can get a connection. If you do, try entering `HTTP/1.0 GET /` and see if you get any apache-looking output. Basically, use telnet as the ultimate poor-man's browser.

Comment: I tried puttytel for connecting to nazar-studio:8080, but it do not work, also tried for 127.0.0.1:8080, it also do not work.

Comment: Then something's blocking your connection. That's the only explanation left.

Comment: Yes there must be, but please guide me, my 3 days had lost fixing it, i can no re-install windows , because have lot of stuff on my machine right now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting to localhost rather than 'nazar-studio'?

Are you sure its running on port 8080?

Is there possibly another process running on port 8080?

Have you checked the error logs? (in #apache install dir#/logs/)

Comment: Yes i had tried, my pc name, localhost, 127.0.0.1. Also tried many different ports by setting it in httpd.conf. nothing works.

No other process is listening on that port, i checked it with TCPView.

Also error log do not show any error rather shows `[Wed May 25 22:10:56 2011] [notice] Child 4216: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.`

Comment: Then it's most likely the microsoft firewall. try disabling it temporarily and if that works, go into control panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall -> Allowed Programs and add apache in there

Comment: Yes i had tried adding Apache to firewall also tried disabling the firewall. but it does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get Apache running on Windows 7 I did the following.

Switch to Administrator:

1. Open a command prompt as Admin, type `net user Administrator /active:yes` and then log off.  At the log on screen you will see two options, log in as Administrator.
2. Install Apache.
3. Edit conf file to how you want.

   - Make sure you have set Listen to 8080 (I have mine left as 80).
   - Don't forget to LoadModule for PHP. Set the ServerName to localhost:8080 (again I have mine as 80).
   - Set DocumentRoot to the htdocs folder where you installed Apache - mine is C:\Program Files\Apache\2.0.40\htdocs. By connecting to localhost:80 you should be able to see the Apache welcome screen.
   - Add type info for PHP (`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3`).
   - Create a virtual host. I am guessing yours would look like

   <VirtualHost *:8080>
     ServerName nazar-studio.localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:/Develop/nazar/htdocs"
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
     ErrorLog logs/error.nazar.log
     CustomLog logs/access.nazar.log combined 
   </VirtualHost>
4. Now Edit your hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and add the subnets you have added:
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.0.1       nazar-studio.localhost
   127.0.0.1       test.localhost
5. Open the command prompt and now type net user Administrator /active:no to disable the admin.  Log off and reconnect as you.
6. Start Apache and you should be able to connect.